# SwiftでJSONを作成しようとするとエラーになる

Tags: swift, json

[WEBの記事](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/34776)を参考に、JSONを作成しようとしています。
クラス定義の直下に以下のように記述すると、エラーになってしまいます。

```
var jsonDic = Dictionary<String, Any>()
jsonDic["id"] = 1
```

1行目ではエラーが出ないのですが、2行目でエラーになります。
エラー内容は以下の通りです。

```
Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
Insert ';'
Expected '(' in argument list of function declaration
Expected '{' in body of function declaration
Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration
Insert 'func '
Expected declaration
Invalid redeclaration of 'jsonDic()'
```

2行目はviewDidLoad内部などに書けば良いのでしょうか？
なぜこのようなエラーが出てしまうのでしょうか？
どうしたらエラーを直せますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「クラス定義の直下」ということは、多分こんな風に書いていませんか？

```
class Hoge {
    var jsonDic = Dictionary<String, Any>()
    jsonDic["id"] = 1
}
```

これですと、`var jsonDic = Dictionary<String, Any>()`の部分はメンバ変数宣言となりますが、`jsonDic["id"] = 1`の方は実行文（Swiftでの用語は違うかもしれませんが）なので、`func fuga() { }`などの中に書く必要があります。（初期化処理なら`func`なしの`init() { }`など）
　「viewDidLoad内部などに書けば良いのでしょうか？」という質問が出る時点で、まずSwiftの最低限の言語仕様の把握や、実際にどう書けばいいかの基礎が飛ばされているようなので、まずは何か入門書を読むなどして基礎部分を勉強した方が良さそうです。